# How do I share a single index page between multiple controllers in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, dry, templating, partials

I have created a partial that includes searchable attributes and paging to replace the default rails scaffolded index view.  It works great on a single model/controller and now **my objective is to share this partial in the DRYest way possible with my other controllers**.  My idea is that there should be ***a way to specify, from a controller, what view to load***, so that I can load the same view from the index method of all controllers.  I am open to other solutions as long as they are DRY or to suggestions on how to better accomplish my objective in a more 'rails way'.  Below is my current working implementation, which requires me to go through about 13 models and call `super` within each index method and to replace the index.html.erb file with the sample from below (which results in 13 identical index files).  I would love to be able to do the following in each index method and call it good:

**Ideal Code**

```
def index
    super
    load_this_custom_page 'shared/index'  # this is the line I'm looking for
end
```

**Current Code**

Controller:

```
def index
    super
end
```

Application Controller:

```
include Modules::TableUI
def index
    results = get_paged_search_results(params)
    params = results[:params]
    @instances = results[:instances]
end
```

modules.rb

```
module Modules
    module TableUI
        def get_paged_search_results(params)
            params[:per_page] = 10 if params[:per_page].blank?
            params[:page] = 1 if params[:page].blank?

            unless params[:columns].blank? || params[:controller].blank?
                model = eval(params[:controller].classify)
                where_clause = ""
                params[:columns].each do |name, value|
                    unless value.blank?
                        where_clause << "(#{model.table_name}.#{name} like '%#{value}%') AND "
                    end
                end
                where_clause << " (1=1)"
                result_set = model.where(where_clause)
                instances = model.paginate(page: params[:page] ,:per_page => params[:per_page]).merge(result_set)

                return {instances:instances,params:params}
            end

            # there has got to be a better way to do this... I just can't find it
            instances = eval(self.class.name.gsub("Controller","").singularize).page(params[:page])
            return {instances:instances,params:params}
        end
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= render  :partial => 'shared/model_table', 
            :locals => {
                :model => @instances.model, 
                :instances => @instances
            } 
%>
```

_model_table.html.erb

```
<h1><%= model.model_name.human.pluralize %></h1>

<%= form_tag("/#{model.model_name.route_key}", method: "get") do %>
    Show <%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([ 10,25,50,100 ], params[:per_page]) %> entries
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:page, params[:page]) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Update table") %>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <% model.column_names.each do |name| %>
                    <th><%= model.human_attribute_name(name) %></th>
                <% end %>
                <th colspan="3"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <% instances.column_names.each_with_index do |attr, i| %>
                    <td><%= text_field_tag("columns[#{attr}]", params[:columns] ? params[:columns][attr] : nil) %></td>
                <% end %>
            </tr>
            <% instances.each do |instance| %>
                <tr>
                    <% instance.attribute_names.each do |attr| %>
                        <td><%= instance[attr.to_sym] %></td>
                    <% end %>
                    <td><%= link_to 'Show', instance %></td>
                    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', "/#{model.model_name.route_key}/#{instance.id}/edit" %></td>
                    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', instance, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate instances %>

<br>

<%= link_to "New #{model.model_name.human}", "/#{model.model_name.route_key}/new" %>
```

Comment: why don't you call render from the controller?

Comment: Perfect @Mohammad, exactly what I was looking for. I ended up putting `render 'shared/index'` in controller#index and deleted all my index pages.  If you care for the vote, create an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what works best for you, but you could do all your processing in your controller and pass to the application controller to do the rendering, for example

```
class SomeContorller < ApplicationController
  def index
    @x = 'some variable'
    super
  end
end
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    render 'shared/index'
  end
end
```

Also a side note, try to avoid using `eval` since it's prone to injection attacks, and use `constantize` instead, replace this line

```
model = eval(params[:controller].classify)
```

with this

```
model = params[:controller].classify.constantize
```

also

```
instances = eval(self.class.name.gsub("Controller","").singularize).page(params[:page])
```

to

```
instances = self.class.name.gsub('Controller','').singularize.constantize.page(params[:page])
```

Answer (score 2):

Every controller in Rails will try to use app/views/layouts/application.html.erb unless you tell otherwise. You could create a custom layout for your index actions, and render your shared template from that new layout file.

Layout:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <%= render 'shared/model_table' %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

And render it in your index actions. This could be achieved by adding this line to your ApplicationController:

```
layout 'layout_with_table', :only => [:index]
```